# Compare options from two selects and hide if value != id

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, hide

I have two `select` elements. I want to compare the value of the selected option in the first select with the `id` of the selected option in second one. My jQuery code looks like this:

```
$("#billing_zone").change(function(){
  if ($('.zone:selected').val() != $('.day').attr("id")) {
    $(".day").hide();
  } else {
    $(".day").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<select name="billing_zone" id="billing_zone" class="select " data-placeholder="">
   <option class="zone" value="10">Birkeland, Tveit, Høvåg</option>
   <option class="zone" value="6">Lillesand Birkeland bedrift</option>
   <option class="zone" value="13">Lillesand</option>
</select>
<select name="billing_delivery_day" id="billing_delivery_day" class="select " data-placeholder="">
   <option class="day" id="10" value="1">Mandag</option>
   <option class="day" id="10" value="2">Tirsdag</option>
   <option class="day" id="6" value="3">Onsdag</option>
   <option class="day" id="13" value="3">Onsdag</option>
</select>
```

However this always hides all of the options. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry forgot about this one. Post edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the `id` selector for this like :

```
$(".day[id="+selected_zone+"]")
```

So hide all the option's on change and show just the one that have related `id` with selected zone value :

```
$("#billing_zone").change(function(){
    var selected_zone = $('.zone:selected').val();

    $(".day").hide(); //Hide all the options
    $(".day[id="+selected_zone+"]").show(); //Show the spedific one that match the selected
});
```

**NOTE :** The `id` attribute should be unique in the same document, so better to use `common classes` or also `data-* attributes` instead.

Hope this helps.

```js
$("#billing_zone").change(function(){
    var selected_zone = $('.zone:selected').val();
    
    $(".day").removeAttr('selected').hide();
    $(".day[id="+selected_zone+"]").show().eq(0).attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="billing_zone" id="billing_zone" class="select " data-placeholder="">
 <option class="zone" value="10">Birkeland, Tveit, Høvåg</option>
 <option class="zone" value="6">Lillesand Birkeland bedrift</option>
 <option class="zone" value="13">Lillesand</option>
</select>
<select name="billing_delivery_day" id="billing_delivery_day" class="select " data-placeholder="">
 <option class="day" id="10" value="1">Mandag</option>
 <option class="day" id="10" value="2">Tirsdag</option>
 <option class="day" id="6" value="3">Onsdag</option><option class="day" id="13" value="3">Onsdag</option>
</select>
```

Comment: One thing, the selected value is still showing even if it is hidden. Any idea how I can refresh select that it choose not hidden element?